# How to load register value to variable C#

Tags: c#, assembly, cpu-registers

Is there any way in C# for loading register value to variable? Like I want to load value of al  register.

Comment: There wouldn't be any C# if you couldn't do this kind of thing.  You can write a C++/CLI class library that uses __asm.  Requiring setting the platform target.  Your register choice was unfortunate though, EAX gets clobbered by the jitter.

Comment: Oks so I will make my classes. TNX.

Comment: You are trying to use the old 16-bit DOS mouse interface.  That is not going to work on a 32-bit machine.  No point in pursuing this, use the Cursor.Position property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - C# isn't tied to any particular CPU architecture, and the use of registered will be decided by the JIT compiler anyway. It's hard to see how you could get any useful information from a register - given that the JIT compiler decides how to use the registers, what would you actually *do* with the value afterwards?

Comment: mov ax,03h;
  int 33h;
  mov m,bx;
  mov y,dx;
  mov x,cx; - mouse input and output. I need it for this

Comment: @FrewCen: That's not the sort of thing you can express in C#. It's a higher level language than that - you get mouse information via events provided by the operating system.

Comment: im making os in cosmos.... and i can't find any document about mouse support in itz.

Comment: @FrewCen: Okay, you should *really, really* have mentioned Cosmos to start with, as that puts it in a somewhat different ball game. There may well be Cosmos-specific extensions which allow you to do this - but I doubt that you'll find very many Cosmos devs here, as it's pretty niche. It's probably worth asking on the cosmos-dev mailing list.

Comment: @FrewCen: Basically, I think you're more likely to get help for cosmos on a cosmos mailing list - questions like this don't really deal with "normal" C#.